# QT4: why bash shell is faster, than the same script, called using QProcess?

Tags: bash, qt4, qprocess

Let me give an example: 
the script should detect, that file creation is finished :

```
#!/bin/bash
CID=$1
TYPE=$2
echo "$TYPE$CID" >scan.log
sleep 1
FILE=$TYPE$CID.jpeg
until [ $(ls -l $FILE | awk '{print $5}') -gt 2000 ]
do
   echo "sleeping" >> scan.log
   sleep 0.4
done
SIZE=`du -h $FILE`
echo "$DT $SIZE " >> scan.log
cp $FILE $TYPE.jpegs
```

When I call execute it from the shell it is very fast : not one line "sleeping" in the output /scan.log/, so the file is ready in 1 second /first sleep is enough/
Meanwhile, when I call the same script from QT, I have to wait more than 5 seconds /more than 14 lines of sleeping/

Is it possible to fix it? as time is critical in my project...
Thank you in advice

Comment: It's not this script that is slow; it's the growth rate of the file "$TYPE$CID.jpeg". What is producing that? In any case, this is not a good way to determine when a file is complete.

Comment: $TYPE$CID.jpeg is an image that I reform on faster machine.
Normally, it is ready before I start to check - as I have not one line of "sleeping" when I check it from the command line...
QT4 :
QProcess bash;
bash.start("./scan.sh p1 p2");
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody, I find out the solution, 
the problem was QT cashe...
so I just used QFileInfo::refresh(), 
QProcess is useless